# Visual Studio: User account you used to sign in is not supported for this application

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I use to sign-in to server explorer & query AzureTable entities.
However since I have updated to Visual Studio Update 4, I have not been able to login.

I tried using same credentials on azure portal & they work perfectly fine.

> Visual Studio
>
> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in
>
> User account you used to sign in is not supported for this
>   application. Please use a different account to sign in.

To my surprise, Google did not return any relevant search result for this error.

P.S. I have double checked my Microsoft account credentials & they are working. This issue has been happening with other team members on different PCs as well.

Comment: Maybe the parent msdn account has removed you, or has expired?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I tried using same credentials on azure portal & they work perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not saying you have the wrong credentials, it's saying the account you have isn't supported in that application. You're doing something that can't be done in the new update, I would contact Micrsofot to figure out why.

Comment: I get this exact same message. I hit cancel and then click on my already signed in account and it goes through fine. Seems like a bug

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have learned to live with this error. This is definitely a bug in VS-2013 Update 4 which Microsoft should look into.

1. I use to sign-out from current subscription in Azure
2. Right click Azure in server explorer
3. Click Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription

It works for one and only time. Next time repeat the process 1 to 3 again.

Comment: I can confirm this on my build/production environment also. It wasn't a problem in Update 3, but after Update 4 I have to sign in using the Server Explorer before publishing my solution to Azure, when I do I get the following message; 

""User account you used to sign in is not supported for this application. Please use a different account to sign in.""

A real pain in the ass. Thanks for your tip, it works for me.

Comment: +1, little different approach but same idea... I opened the Server Explorer, closed out when it prompted me for credentials and then clicked "Sign Out".  Then clicked "Sign In" and signed in and when I went back in to Publish all was right with the world again.

Comment: VS2017 Community, Same issue but I am unable to get the appropriate data that I am willing to have.

Answer (score 6):

I believe I've had the exact same issue. Here's how I resolved it:

In the log-in page that "pops up" from Visual Studio I deleted the Microsoft account id that I usually sign in with and entered a different account ID that I own.

As soon as I finished typing the account id in, the page was refreshed and I was redirected to a Microsoft account log-in page. In that log-in page I made sure to type in the correct Microsoft account ID (the one I use for Azure) and its password. Having successfully signed in there, I was able to continue working as usual.

This was roughly based on guidance I found in [this Microsoft Technet discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/40ac7a3d-12f0-47c5-9cee-97dd5867ddf0/unable-to-sign-in-when-trying-to-publish-web-role-to-azure?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution to worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Same here with Visual Studio 2015. I did logout user from visual studio and log in again and problem went away for good.

Answer (score 0):

I recently received the same error after deploying an app to Azure and trying to connect to a DB server I had launched. When you first create an account, MS gives you a default active directory where you're sign in account is assigned the role of global administrator. You need to create a user account for this directory and use these credentials to sign in (different from signing into Visual Studio, you're providing credentials to access something on Azure).

In the Azure Portal, open up Active Directory and click on the default directory (or whichever one your project lives in). Go to the Users tab and select "Add User" from the panel at the bottom of the window. For "Type of User" select "New user in your organization", fill in the rest of the details and create the account. You get a temporary password and an awkward username. Now if you refresh server explorer you should be able to enter these credentials (and get prompted to enter a new password).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to inform all of you that I had the same problem. Since this Sunday it disappeared magically on my VS 2013 Update 4 on all my machines. Here are my experiences:

- Last week I had to re-enter my subscription after any VS-restart.
- Sunday I opened VS and I was asked to reenter my VS-credentials in the upper-right corner.
- I did not reenter my VS-credentials but simply expanded "Azure" in the Server Explorer and then expanded "SQL Databases" which led to the login-prompt formerly. Now the "Server Explorer" acted as expected.
- I thought that the missing VS-login was the solution but I was wrong. Even with my VS logged on I know can restart the Studio as many times I want -> it works.
- To ensure this I did several restarts of my machine too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stuff up on Microsoft's side, just replace your email address with one that isn't linked already and it will work.

**To fix it: Use your a different email address with the same account through visual studio.**